# Bypass internal application calls to proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, gcloud

I have created a windows VM in GCloud and have updated proxy settings to ensure all calls go through the proxy.
There are two cases:

1. I set the Proxy setting to call the proxy server. This ensure all the calls that are made through any browser, go through the proxy.
2. I have setup http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables, with this, any curl commands I hit through Command Prompt or Bash also go via the proxy.

Now I have a case where I need to bypass a few calls and not allow them through the proxy.
This is only required by some desktop Apps I have in my VM and not for the browser call.

CASE1: From some research, in order to bypass browsers call, there is a .pac file where we can added domains to bypass
CASE2: But for non-browser calls, I could only find a way to add a no_proxy environment variable.

Following are my questions related to CASE2

Question 1? When I setup no_proxy env variable, git bash does not seem to respect that unless I set it explicitly in git bash before making any call. So is this the right way to do? or I am missing something.

Question 2: Google internal makes a few calls from the VM to get Metadata, those calls are getting proxied. But even though I update the no_proxy env variable, it still does not respect and calls still go through the proxy. where should I set this up so that I can bypass these internal VM calls to go through without being proxied?

Following is my setup

1. VM is on GCP with windows image
2. Proxy server is Squid setup on a static public IP.
3. The applications are calling some internal APIs
4. The vm calls http://metadata.google.internal API

Nay help on this would be highly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: The answer depends on which proxy, how you set up the proxy, and which libraries/APIs the applications are calling. Edit your question with those details.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have updated the details

Comment: Can you Please have a look at this [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/1086) on no_proxy environment variable and [configuring proxy](https://medium.com/google-cloud/configuring-gcloud-gsutil-and-bq-to-use-proxy-servers-4f09dbaf42c2) on gcloud for more information.